# There is no Tables option in Azure Storage Account

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have consulted the documentation for creating an Azure Storage Account and succeeded in doing so, but there is only the option for containers and not for Tables or any other option as the documentation said so.
This feature has been moved?
How do I create an Azure Storage Account with the tables option available?

Comment: Can you provide information about your project and dependencies: `.csproj`, `package.config`, etc.?

Comment: @joncloud Sorry I will remove the c# tag. The problem was that the Tables option didn't appear once I create the Storage Account. But it appeared once I created a new Storage Account with the perfomance set to Standard instead of Premium.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check your storage account type, if it's a blob storage kind only or premium tier kind, then it's no table storage there.

Please make sure the storage account is `General-Purpose V2 or V1` and `standard tier`, you can check it's type as per screenshot below:

[image]

And [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-overview#types-of-storage-accounts) is the full list of the azure storage account type, you can see the table storage is supported from which type.

Comment: I did that. I just created a new storage account and set it to Standard instead of premium and the Tables option appeared now! So there's no tables feature for premium perfomance?

Comment: @CamiloEnriquez, yes, the premium performance does not support table feature. You should only use the standard one.

Comment: No tables in Premium?  That is insane.